# [Lucene]What is the overhead in IndexReader/Searcher

Tags: performance, lucene

Most of the documentation of Lucene advises to keep a single instance of the indexReader and reuse it because of the overhead of opening a new Reader.

However i find it hard to see what this overhead is based and what influences it.

related to this is how much overhead does having an open IndexReader actualy cause?

The context for this question is:
We currently run a clustered tomcat stack where we do fulltext from the ServletContainer. 
These searches are done on a separate Lucene indexes for each client because each client only seeks in his own data. Each of these indexes contains ranging from a few thousand to (currently) about 100.000 documents.

Because of the clustered tomcat nodes, any client can connect on any tomcat node.
Therefore keeping the IndexReader open would actually mean keep a few thousand indexReaders open on each tomcat node. This seems like a bad idea, however constantly reopening doesn't seem like a very good idea either.

While its possible for me to somewhat change the way we deploy Lucene if its not needed i'd rather not.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the field cache is the slowest piece of Lucene to warm up, although other things like filters and segment pointers contribute. The specific amount kept in cache will depend on your usage, especially with stuff like how much data is stored (as opposed to just indexed).

You can use whatever memory usage investigation tool is appropriate for your environment to see how much Lucene itself takes up for your application, but keep in mind that "warm up cost" also refers to the various caches that the OS and file system keep open which will probably not appear in `top` or whatever you use.

You are right that having thousands of indexes is not a common practice. The standard advice is to have them share an index and use filters to ensure that the appropriate results are returned.

Since you are interested in performance, you should keep in mind that having thousands of indices on the server will result in thousands of files strewn all across the disk, which will lead to tons of seek time that wouldn't happen if you just had one big index. Depending on your requirements, this may or may not be an issue.

As a side note: it sounds like you may be using a networked file system, which is a big performance hit for Lucene.